# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' - openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, save, openpyxl

Hello I have the following error using this code:

```
def save_wb(self):
    """
    Save the final result file
    """
    time.sleep(2)
    output_excel_path = self.output_name + ".xlsx"
    excel_list_name_delete.append(output_excel_path)

    exported = False
    while not exported:
        try:                    
            self.output_excel.save(output_excel_path)
            exported = True
        except IOError:
            print("Exportation interrupted")

    return
```

Error:

```
 File "C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/XXX.py", line XXX, in save_wb
self.output_excel.save(output_excel_path)
 File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 367, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 284, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 266, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 83, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 217, in _write_worksheets
    self._write_comment(ws)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 185, in _write_comment
    vml = fromstring(self.workbook.vba_archive.read(ws.legacy_drawing))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

What I understood in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881739/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-read), there is a bug on the openpyxl code. It seems it is not yet solved. However, I wonder to know if there exist a possible solution for this case without using `sheet._comments = []`.

Comment: how is this related to tkinter? remove the `tkinter` tag

Comment: what I understood from the error is that this: `self.workbook.vba_archive` is `None`

Comment: Which version of `openpyxl` do you have? I dug into the code, and the problem seems to be fixed in the version I have (3.0.6)

Comment: Matiiss - Yeah, in this case and the other post case we used Tkinter, I don't know if it is related... but I thought it was a good idea to mention it. 

@sommervold - L have the last, but this is new, because in my older computer I can run it. Do you think it is a good idea to uninstall Anaconda and re-install it again?

Comment: @SultryT. This bug should have been fixed two years ago, in [this commit](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/commit/77f6d556503be56d9e9df40f949cfdfe63ee9301?view=inline). This was part of version 2.6.1 and onwards. Try to head into the excel.py file and look at the if-statement surrounding line 185, what does it say?

Comment: @sommervold Sorry for the late response, actually you were right. I changed Anaconda to VStudio and update the last version and that was the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been mentioned by @sommervold just update the last version on your pc in another terminal.